# To use th OpenCV image Stitcher without the OpenCV library

Tags: opencv, opencv-stitching

Is it possible to use/compile the OpenCV image stitcher module as a standalone project, without having to include the entire OpenCV library?
I see the stitcher module has dependencies to the OpenCV core, but, is there any other standalone variant of this stitcher module?

Thanks

Comment: since the stitcher module is high level composition of many low level openCV functionalities, I doubt it will be easy to separate the stitcher functionality ;)
but since openCV is open source, you are free to do that yourself (but keep in mind to hold all license restrictions if there are any!).

Comment: You can rebuild OpenCV as static libs and the just link in the code you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use/compile the OpenCV image stitcher module as a standalone project, without having to include the entire OpenCV library?

You can compile only a part of OpenCV with CMake, but you always have to compile the [core functionality](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/table_of_content_core/table_of_content_core.html). That is not the "entire OpenCV library" but certainly a "big" part. (You have to decide that for yourself)

> I see the stitcher module has dependencies to the OpenCV core, but, is there any other standalone variant of this stitcher module?

Not in OpenCV afaik.

As @Micka pointed out in the comments you can try to pull the imagestitching functionality from the sources, if you'd really have to.